# Bad battery life on Xubuntu 16.04 Lenovo T460s

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, power-management, lenovo, battery

The battery life of my new `Lenovo T460s` is very bad (about 4,5h with a little bit browsing and half display contrast).

`Xubuntu 16.04` shows two batteries (`SANYO 00HW022` and `SANYO 01AV405`). They were drained one after the other. I'm not sure how the batteries are integrated in the notebook, but I ordered it with only one (fixed) battery.

Is there something I can do to increase the battery life? Is it a recognition problem of the battery?

Comment: It would be good to add more information about your setup. Did you install anything like tlp or is it a normal xubuntu Installation? I think it is a new skylake CPU, normally newer hardware is not so well supported even if it is intel.

Comment: according to the lenovo shop, there are two build-in batteries (one front and one back), so it is normal that the OS sees both.

Comment: linux skylake support is currently woeful. Processor cannot use most of the low power states it has.
Nothing you can do for a little while until it improves. http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/41713.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** As Ubuntu [16.04 is not officially released yet](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) you should use launchpad to [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so the developers are aware of this and can track it.

Comment: Does it have Optimus hybrid graphics or intel only?

Comment: It's just an Intel, as the nvidia dedicated version was not released in Germany

Comment: If you're from Germany you may ask your question in the german [ThinkPad-Forum](https://thinkpad-forum.de/forums/22-Linux).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do to increase the battery-life is installing tlp with some additional stuff

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw acpi-call-dkms
```

`tlp` is in the official ubuntu repo since 15.10. More information are available [here](http://linrunner.de/tlp). The `man`-page is in english

```
man tlp
```

You can also install `thinkfan` which can reduce the noise-level and can save some energy. You should also install `powertop`

```
sudo apt-get install thinkfan powertop
```

`powertop` is a really powerful tool writen by intel.

Comment: Can you help me analysing my powertop output?

http://pastebin.com/n2w1anTp

Answer (score 1):

You should watch your computer enviroment (eg, making sure the the cpu doesn't get too hot, don't run too much applications, so on.) You could use tlp. tlp is excellent on many Linux computers.

```
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

Comment: (to switch between ac and battery, type  `tlp ac` and battery: `tlp battery`

Answer (score 0):

As reported in previous comments, Skylake support for laptops in Linux is currently not perfect. More info here: https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/41713.html. If you start Powertop, you'll probably find out that the deepest power saving state you can get is PC2 (under Idle stats/Package), which is apparently quite bad, and even potentially dangerous for the cpu. Launch powertop with `sudo powertop --auto-tune`, and see if you can get anything better: using that option I can now get a PC7 state; notice that first I updated the bios to the latest version (1.13), but I'm not sure this makes any difference. Hopefully next kernel updates will make things work better.
Nice machine, anyway :)